# ImportError: cannot import name 'safe_join'

Tags: django, docker, aws

Recibo este error cuando ejecuto un proyecto Django con docker con AWS S3

[image: Error django AWS]

Comment: Prueba a recrear la imagen docker con `pip install boto --upgrade`

Comment: Ya probe y tampoco :(..